# Substitution of logical equivalents

Tags: logic

In classical propositional logic, if two formulas are logically equivalent then they are substitutable. That is, if we can prove $A \leftrightarrow B$, then we can substitute $B$ for $A$.

Does this property hold of formulas involving quantifiers, etcetera, in (classical) first order logic? (Assuming we rename variables where necessary). For example, $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall z \forall x \exists y (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$. Are they therefore substitutable for one another (again, renaming variables if necessary).

---

Also, I cannot find anywhere where this is stated explicitly of the first-order case. If anyone has a reference, I would be very pleased.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

See:

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=q-YEuuZ_j8EC&pg=PA122) (1967): **Replacement Theorem**, page 122;
- Peter Andrews, [An introduction to mathematical logic and type theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nV4zAsWAvT0C&pg=PA94) (1986): **Substitutivity of Implication**, page 89 and **Extended Substitutivity of Implication and Equivalence**, page 94;
- Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books/about/Mathematical_logic.html?id=a9zuAAAAMAAJ) (1967), **Equivalence Theorem**, page 34.