# How are statements laid out in deductive proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

so I am doing deductive proof, I know this contains a lot of laws that you need to be familiar with. And I have all that I need here. However, I don't known when to use more than one premise. For example say:

---

1: A ⇒ B     Premise 
2: C ⇒ D     Premise 
3: B ∨ D ⇒ E Premise 
4: ¬E         Premise 
5: ¬(B ∨ D) **from 3 & 4 modus tollens** 
Here what I don't understand is when it says 3 & 4 modus tollens, How is 3 & 4 actually laid out before applying modus tollens? 
Also the modus tollens rule says:
¬p ∧ (p ⇒ q) ⇒ ¬p 
So how can it be applied to 3 & 4?

Comment: If "B or D" would be true, E would be as well. But E is false, so "B or D" must be false.

Comment: The second last line probably contains a typo.

Comment: For example do you think we can apply the law of negation on this: ¬p∧¬¬Q

Comment: What is "the law of negation" ?

Comment: ¬(¬p) ≡ p isn't it?

Comment: We can, applying [Substitution of logical equivalents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113197/substitution-of-logical-equivalents); thus, from $\lnot P \land \lnot \lnot Q$ and $\lnot \lnot Q \equiv Q$, we can derive $\lnot P \land Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, in a derivation, when we apply a *rule*, this rule must use (one or more) formulas already present in the derivation.

Thus, if we refer to lines in the derivation by numbers, the simple rule must be:

> in line $n$ apply *Rule X* to formulas in lines $i$ and $j$, with $i,j < n$.

With [Modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) we can refer either to a *rule* :

> $P\to Q,\lnot Q\vdash \lnot P$,

or to a *tautology* :

> $((P\to Q)\land \neg Q)\to \neg P$.

In the first case, your line 5 is fine: it follows from lines 3) and 4) by *MT*.

In the second case, to be "formal", we have to interpose some intermediate steps :

> 4') $((B \lor D) \to E)\land \neg E$ --- from 3) and 4) by [Conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)
>
> 4'') $[((B \lor D) \to E)\land \neg E] \to \neg ((B \lor D) \to E)$ --- tautology : *Modus Tollens*

to get :

> > 5) $\neg (B \lor D) \to E$ --- from 4') and 4'') by *Modus ponens*.

Comment: So say I had ¬p∧¬¬Q then is it ok to apply the law of negation>