# Can $p\rightarrow q$ be replaced with $p'$ or $q$?

Tags: logic

I know that $p\rightarrow q$ can be written as $p$' or $q$.
Can an equation like ($p'$ or $q$ or $r$) be written as $((p\rightarrow  q)\text{ or }r)$?

Comment: Yes, you can... See [Substitution of logical equivalents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113197/substitution-of-logical-equivalents?r=SearchResults&s=1|65.4991)

Comment: Why write "$\rightarrow$" as a symbol, but "or" as a word?  Why not use both symbols ($\rightarrow, \vee$) or both words (if, then; or).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed. The `or` operation is associative, so when we have several `or`s in a row, we are allowed to put brackets wherever we want and write

```
p' or q or r
(p' or q) or r
(p -> q) or r
```

*Usually*, you would want to go the other way, though. Certainly, to me, the top row looks simpler to grok than the bottom row.